# urn problem(without replacement)

Tags: probability

A urn contain $r$ white ball and $N-r$ black ball. If one draw the ball without replacement. What is the probability of the $i$-th result is a white ball.
By using the law of total probability, I got $$\sum_{m=0}^{i-1} \frac{C_{m}^{r} C_{i-1-m}^{N-r}}{C_{i-1}^{N}} \frac{r-m}{N-m}$$

But I can't sum it up. Is there are some alternative solution

Comment: And I don't know the case that r is less the i

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $r/N$ regardless of $i$. If we don't know what the other drawn balls are, there is no way that they can affect the result, so it's  equivalent to the initial trial.

You can do this the combinatorics way, but after adding up the endless $a\choose b$ stuff, you will come out to $r/N$ at the end.

Comment: So, how can I calculate the sum

Comment: @user134927 Why do you want to? Your question clearly states "Is there (are) some alternative solution" The answer is "yes, it must be r/N". There is also a cogent argument by MohammadAliBaydou which says the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's transform the problem to something equivalent. Assume that you did all $N$ trials, and each time you took a white ball, you appended $0$ to a binary string. For the black balls, you appended $1$. This will always give you a binary string with $(r)$ $0$'s and $(N - r)$ $1$'s:

$$01011011$$
Now, the question becomes: What is the probability that any randomly selected bit in the string will be a $0$?

That would be: $$\large \frac{r}{N}$$

Comment: but I draw the ball without replacement. The probability of drawing a white ball  after each draw should not be constant

Comment: It isn't constant here. Once you appended $(r)$ $0$'s in the binary string, the probability of appending one more becomes $0$.